# mongo: update matched elements of array that is in other array

Tags: mongodb

I have next schema of mongo document:

```
{
"array1" : [
    {
        "array2" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "field" : 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to find elements in array2 with {id: 1} and update its "field". I tried next:

```
db.filmCitation.update({ "array1.array2": {$elemMatch: {"id": 1, field: {$gte: 2}} } }, {$set: {"array1.array2.field": 23})
```

But I must specify right index in arrays. For one array can be used "$". And what can I do when needs to find in several arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand your input with multiple documents in the array, and a sample output?

Comment: You want to use the [$ positional update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays), but this operator cannot be used to traverse multiple or nested arrays. The alternative is to reconsider the schema or retrieve the document, update it in client code, and then insert the document again or update just the altered fields with knowledge of the specific indexes that need to be updated.